# SQL Server logs location

Tags: sql-server

How can I retrieve all T-SQL statements fired by users in last one month in SQL Server database?

I have looked at sys tables but I am not able to figure out where the logs are stored.

Comment: Unless you have some auditing in place already you don't. The query engine does not store every single query executed against the server. And certainly not indefinitely.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Can you let me know how can I enable auditing to store all the logs.

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't want to store every query that is executed. The amount of data would be astronomical. You can look into extended events to capture executing queries. But on even a moderately busy system this could equate to multiple gigs of data every day.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server we don't keep track of users who execute queries, except for some DML/DDL captured by the default trace or run `SQL Profiler`

Better to create a server side trace or enable SQL Audit to track down activity from users that you want to track or you don't trust.

If you are using any DMV for capture data, remember that DMV data gets reset if the DMV is cleared out, sql server is restarted, etc.

SQL query:

```
USE master
go
SELECT sdest.DatabaseName 
    ,sdes.session_id
    ,sdes.[host_name]
    ,sdes.[program_name]
    ,sdes.client_interface_name
    ,sdes.login_name
    ,sdes.login_time
    ,sdes.nt_domain
    ,sdes.nt_user_name
    ,sdec.client_net_address
    ,sdec.local_net_address
    ,sdest.ObjName
    ,sdest.Query
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sdes
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS sdec ON sdec.session_id = sdes.session_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT db_name(dbid) AS DatabaseName
        ,object_id(objectid) AS ObjName
        ,ISNULL((
                SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
                FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ), '') AS Query

    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
    ) sdest
where sdes.session_id <> @@SPID 
--and sdes.nt_user_name = '' -- Put the username here !
ORDER BY sdec.session_id
```

Query Store (SQL Server 2016+) instead of the DMV's. This gives better ability to look into historical data, as well as faster lookups and very efficient to capture short-running queries that can't be captured by sp_who/sp_whoisactive as well.